# Diagonal-preserving low-rank approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Are there any methods for obtaining a low-rank approximation of a matrix that preserves the diagonal? For example, given a square matrix $A$, determine if there exists $A'$ such that
$$
\|A-A'\| <= \delta,
\\
\|diag(A)-diag(A')\| <= \epsilon,
\\rank(A') <= \rho.
$$
Other variations of this problem can be considered.

I'm particularly interested in the case of null diagonals, but I reckon the general case is interesting as well.

Comment: If $A=I$, then any $B$ of lower rank will have $\|A-I\|\ge1$.

Comment: @Chrystomath That's why I formulated the problem as "determine if there exists".

Comment: So what you mean is "Determine conditions on $A$ such that there exists $A'$,..." ?

Comment: @Chrystomath That's one way to put it, although I am more interested in algorithms that either give you a valid matrix or tell you there is none.

Comment: @Chrystomath You can always tune the parameters so that there is a valid matrix, and then try to optimize those.